# Внедрение дизайна в приложении на Yii

Tags: веб-дизайн, php, yii

До недавнего момента самостоятельно занимался как разработкой веб-приложений на Yii-framework'е, так и созданием и вёрсткой дизайна. Сейчас работу по созданию шаблонов выполняет дизайнер, до этого не имевший опыта работы с этим фреймворком, да и вообще в написании скриптов. В связи с этим вопрос: есть ли какие-нибудь решения, позволяющие облегчить процесс внедрения шаблонов на Yii-приложения? Или, может быть, есть какие-нибудь альтернативы этому фреймворку, в которых дзайнеру не приходилось бы писать скрипты самому?

Comment: в любом случае ему придется постичь "переменные" и циклы хотя-бы. это касается любых темплейтных движков. если он упрется - его надо гнать.

Comment: вроде как в йии можно прикрутить Twig, синтаксис у него простой и разобраться дезигнер вполне сможет :)

Comment: @eicto, если вы заставляете дизайнера внедрять шаблоны, гнать нужно вас

Comment: @eicto, @digi, да, я задумывался над использованием шаблонизатора. Но не думаю, что его использование будет оправдано в каждом проекте только ради того, чтобы было проще верстать. Однако за предложение спасибо.

Comment: @VasyOk не дизайнера, а верстальщика. Роль которого как я понимаю выполняет дизайнер. Если он не может в шаблонах ориентироваться, то и верстка у него будет соответствующая.

Comment: @xphoenyx, твиг это не только "упрощатель верстки", у него есть возможность наследования шаблонов, что выводит верстку и логику приложения в целом на качественно новый уровень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть пускай дизайнер лучше рисует, верстает его дизайн пускай верстальщик, он же кстати должен знать что такое JS и может внедрить легкие скрипты, т.к. для всего остального есть фрон-энд-разработчики.

Этот тупарылый процесс, когда нужно изменить какую нибудь хреньку на сайте и таск отправляется дизайнеру...

Я как программист помню как и что я тут делал, какие переменные идут в шаблон и где он находится, написал ли я под этот блок виджет или нет, а может стоит? Вам всегда будет проще ориентироваться во всем этом. Дизайнер тут - как гуманитарий на стройке.

Comment: Думаю, мы так и поступим, ибо освоение программирования ради того, чтобы сверстать шаблон на Yii, не только малосмысленно, но и затратно по времени. Благодарю за ответ.